# How can I bring back a specific portion of a json document?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that queries a CosmosDB for the documents it contains in a collection:

```
module.exports = function (context, req) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

if (context.bindings) {
  var doc = context.bindings.inputDocument;

  context.log('Get ready');
  context.res = {status: 200, body: doc};
  context.log(context.res);
}
else {
  context.res = {
    status: 400,
    body: "Something went wrong"
  };
}
context.done();
};
```

This query brings back everything, where I'm just looking for a specific item to be returned. How can I refactor this to just pull back certain elements? I've tried things like using:

```
doc.id
```

Here is the json structure of the sql api configured cosmosdb:

```
{
 "id": "1",
 "drink": "gin_and_tonic",
 "ingredients": [
   "2 ounces gin",
   "2 lime wedges",
   "3–4 ounces tonic water"
   ],
 "directions": "Add gin to a highball glass filled with ice. Squeeze in 
lime wedges to taste, then add them to glass. Add tonic water; stir to 
combine.",
 "glass": [
   "highball",
   "hurricane"
   ],
 "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1523905491727-d82018a34d75? 
   ixlib=rb- 
     0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=52731e6d008be93fda7f5af1145eac12&auto=fo 
   rmat&fit=crop&w=750&q=80"
}
```

Instead of doc but this does not return anything. I'm also trying to use the @azure/cosmos npm module but it seems a bit overkill and does not seem to use the input defined in the function directly. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the mongodb api ?

Comment: No - it’s a azure http trigger function where you supply an input (in my case cosmosdb) wysiwyg for the extent of the nodejs code

Comment: cosmos db uses the sql api

Comment: Can you share the structure of your documents ?

Comment: Now sharing structure in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var doc = context.bindings.inputDocument;` the input binding is an array of document even though there's only one document. That's why `doc.id` doesn't return anything.

Two solutions:

1. Filter in response as what you have tried.

   ```
   var doc = context.bindings.inputDocument;
   var idArray = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
       idArray.push(doc[i].id);
   }   

   context.log('Get ready');
   context.res = {status: 200, body: idArray};
   context.log(context.res);
   ```
2. Filter in query. Go to `function.json`, in binding of cosmosdb, add `"sqlQuery": "SELECT c.id FROM c"` like this

   ```
   {
     "name": "inputDocument",
     "type": "cosmosDB",
     "direction": "in",
     "databaseName": "DBNAME",
     "collectionName": "COLLECTIONNAME",
     "connectionStringSetting": "CosmosDBConnectionString",
     "sqlQuery": "SELECT c.id FROM c"
   }
   ```

   and you can use original code `context.res = {status: 200, body: doc};` to get desired items.

Comment: I think this second option seems more like what works for my application... I’ll give this a shot asap - thanks!